discrete-time survival model (output)
Which of these two functions is more appropriate for a discrete-time survival analysis? Suppose there are 8 time points in the dataset. The output needs to include a single estimation for time and separate estimations for each level of Time? In short: do i need to include Time or factor(Time) into the analysis?
Gompertz_Model_Baseline <- glm(formula = event ~ Time,
                              family = binomial(link = "cloglog"),
                              data = Scania_PersonPeriod_Train)

summary(Gompertz_Model_Baseline)


Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.168556   0.072451  -57.54   <2e-16 ***
time        0.072376   0.004185   17.30   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

second model:
Gompertz_Model_Baseline <- glm(formula = event ~ factor(Time),
                              family = binomial(link = "cloglog"),
                              data = Scania_PersonPeriod_Train)

 summary(Gompertz_Model_Baseline)


Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -4.0762     0.1961 -20.784  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Time)2    0.2717     0.2640   1.029 0.303511    
factor(Time)3   -0.1942     0.3018  -0.643 0.519926    
factor(Time)4    0.1789     0.2774   0.645 0.518810    
factor(Time)5    0.3349     0.2701   1.240 0.214988    
factor(Time)6    0.3844     0.2701   1.423 0.154699    
factor(Time)7    0.3722     0.2748   1.355 0.175537  

                       
                       


The choice is pretty much up to you, based on your understanding of the subject matter and the assumptions you are willing to make. You might consider a third, intermediate approach.
The second model, treating Time as a factor, makes no assumptions about how the hazard changes over time. That lack of assumption about hazard as a function of time is similar to how a Cox model in continuous time works. That model uses up 6 degrees of freedom, however (the number of coefficients related to Time that you need to estimate).
The first model only devotes one degree of freedom to Time, but it implicitly assumes that Time is linearly related to the link function of the model (complementary log-log here). Strict linear relationships don't necessarily hold in practice.
You could consider using an intermediate approach: modeling Time flexibly, for example with a restricted cubic spline. That allows for non-linearity in Time, smoothing somewhat while typically using up fewer degrees of freedom that the second model.

thanks for the advice. Let me double-check my understanding from your comment with you. You mean both functions can be used for discrete time survival analysis. But when we include the as. factor (time) into the model, we make no assumption about how the hazard would change over time. Please correct me if I am wrong. Suppose, based on other studies, the hazard rate and hazard ratio are constant numbers (for example, hazard ratio = 3.2 and hazard rate = 0.6). Then, which one of these methods would be more appropriate?

I got the idea of including as.factor(time) into the model from this link https://rpubs.com/corey_sparks/63112 , whereas other sites, such as this one https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/discrete-time-survival/, just include time directly into the model.

@elisa this web page used a simple linear model for the baseline log-hazard over time because a plot of log(-log(1-hazard)) (the complementary log-log function) was close to linear in time. If you're assured of that fine, but the as.factor(time) allows for more complicated baseline functions. If you're using a cloglog link you are assuming a constant hazard ratio, although including an interaction between your predictor and as.factor(time) gets around that, as in the other page.

@elisa you need to think about your definition of "hazard rate = 0.6" Technically, the hazard in a fixed-interval discrete-time model is the probability that there will be a failure during a time period given that you've survived to the beginning of that time period. Or do you mean that the number of failures per time period are the same from period to period? If you're looking at values from the literature, authors aren't always very clear about that. The regression spline that I suggest can be a good compromise that allows you to test those possibilities in your own data.

again, thank you so much for your time. I am very grateful for the advice you have provided. I am still confused. I reviewed the definition of discrete time survival analysis again, and in the literature, it is mentioned that in discrete time survival analysis, the time variable is considered categorical. Time is divided into discrete intervals, and the hazard is assumed constant within each interval, highlighting that time should be included as as.factor(time) in the model.

Sorry, I need to ask this question again, Can we include time (not as.factor(time)) into a discrete time survival model and have just one estimation for it (and not for each level of time seperately) especially when we have a longitudinal study?

@elisa as.factor(time) makes the fewest assumptions and might be the "safest" choice if you have enough data. If you are willing to assume or can document (as on this page) that a single linear term in time will adequately describe the data, then you can just use time. It's hard to know which will be best in general. Being a longitudinal study has nothing to do with this; most survival models are fundamentally longitudinal.

Great, thank you so much for your time and kindness again.
